# Docker task starting then stopping without any error

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I have a Marathon task that starts a Docker container.  It consistently starts, then exits after about 10 seconds.  I can't figure out why it's exiting.  If I run the exact same Docker command-line directly, the container stays up.  I'd appreciate any debugging tips. I am attaching Mesos Master, Slave , Kernel & Marathon Logs.

**Mesos Version:** 0.28.1
**Marathon:** 1.1.1

**Task Details:** cpu 0.5, Memory: 32 MB, Disk Space: 32 MB

**Mesos Slave Logs**

```
I0729 13:27:57.324440 12645 slave.cpp:1361] Got assigned task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 for framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:57.327953 12644 gc.cpp:83] Unscheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000' from gc
I0729 13:27:57.328632 12644 gc.cpp:83] Unscheduling '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000' from gc
I0729 13:27:57.329421 12645 slave.cpp:1480] Launching task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 for framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:57.330699 12645 paths.cpp:528] Trying to chown '/tmp/mesos/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000/executors/basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889/runs/4e7f7e96-0318-4699-9fb1-8f0a4b3eb0e8' to user 'root'
I0729 13:27:57.339612 12645 slave.cpp:5367] Launching executor basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 with resources cpus(*):0.1; mem(*):32 in work directory '/tmp/mesos/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000/executors/basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889/runs/4e7f7e96-0318-4699-9fb1-8f0a4b3eb0e8'
I0729 13:27:57.341789 12645 slave.cpp:1698] Queuing task 'basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889' for executor 'basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889' of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:57.350003 12652 docker.cpp:1041] Starting container '4e7f7e96-0318-4699-9fb1-8f0a4b3eb0e8' for executor 'basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889' and framework '09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000'
E0729 13:27:58.646698 12651 slave.cpp:3773] Container '4e7f7e96-0318-4699-9fb1-8f0a4b3eb0e8' for executor 'basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889' of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 failed to start: Container exited on error: exited with status 1
I0729 13:27:58.648016 12645 slave.cpp:3879] Executor 'basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889' of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 has terminated with unknown status
I0729 13:27:58.648771 12645 slave.cpp:3002] Handling status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 7cb5dc80-8c90-4933-83a1-c68e4a1369bf) for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 from @0.0.0.0:0
W0729 13:27:58.650879 12645 docker.cpp:1302] Ignoring updating unknown container: 4e7f7e96-0318-4699-9fb1-8f0a4b3eb0e8
I0729 13:27:58.652117 12651 status_update_manager.cpp:320] Received status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 7cb5dc80-8c90-4933-83a1-c68e4a1369bf) for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:58.653165 12651 status_update_manager.cpp:824] Checkpointing UPDATE for status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 7cb5dc80-8c90-4933-83a1-c68e4a1369bf) for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:58.658000 12643 slave.cpp:3400] Forwarding the update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 7cb5dc80-8c90-4933-83a1-c68e4a1369bf) for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 to master@xx.xx.xx.xxx:5050
I0729 13:27:58.751868 12650 status_update_manager.cpp:392] Received status update acknowledgement (UUID: 7cb5dc80-8c90-4933-83a1-c68e4a1369bf) for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:58.752244 12650 status_update_manager.cpp:824] Checkpointing ACK for status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 7cb5dc80-8c90-4933-83a1-c68e4a1369bf) for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:58.757303 12652 slave.cpp:3990] Cleaning up executor 'basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889' of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:58.757876 12650 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000/executors/basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889/runs/4e7f7e96-0318-4699-9fb1-8f0a4b3eb0e8' for gc 6.99999123038222days in the future
I0729 13:27:58.758280 12650 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000/executors/basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889' for gc 6.99999122602074days in the future
I0729 13:27:58.758572 12650 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000/executors/basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889/runs/4e7f7e96-0318-4699-9fb1-8f0a4b3eb0e8' for gc 6.99999122381926days in the future
I0729 13:27:58.758597 12652 slave.cpp:4078] Cleaning up framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:58.758901 12650 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000/executors/basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889' for gc 6.99999122165333days in the future
I0729 13:27:58.759013 12646 status_update_manager.cpp:282] Closing status update streams for framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:58.759237 12650 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000' for gc 6.99999121670222days in the future
I0729 13:27:58.759496 12650 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7/frameworks/09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000' for gc 6.99999121438518days in the future
```

**Marathon Logs**

```
[2016-07-29 13:27:56,985] INFO Received offers WANTED notification (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:56,986] INFO => revive offers NOW, canceling any scheduled revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:56,986] INFO 2 further revives still needed. Repeating reviveOffers according to --revive_offers_repetitions 3 (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:56,986] INFO => Schedule next revive at 2016-07-29T07:58:01.983Z in 4999 milliseconds, adhering to --min_revive_offers_interval 5000 (ms) (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:57,191] INFO Request Launch for task 'basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889', version '2016-07-29T07:57:56.450Z'. 1 tasksToLaunch, 0 in flight, 0 confirmed.  not backing off (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:57,193] INFO No tasks left to launch. Stop receiving offers for /basic-3, 2016-07-29T07:57:56.450Z (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:57,194] INFO removing matcher ActorOfferMatcher(Actor[akka://marathon/user/launchQueue/2/0-basic-3#-1947978475]) (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:57,194] INFO Received offers NOT WANTED notification, canceling 2 revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:57,221] INFO Processing LaunchEphemeral(LaunchedEphemeral(task [basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889],AgentInfo(xx.xx.xx.xxx,Some(09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7),Buffer()),2016-07-29T07:57:56.450Z,Status(2016-07-29T07:57:57.163Z,None,None),Vector(31623))) for task [basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889] (mesosphere.marathon.core.launcher.impl.OfferProcessorImpl:ForkJoinPool-2-worker-41)
[2016-07-29 13:27:57,221] INFO Finished processing b2501f80-c821-4b1a-9f67-c008739a4e06-O1. Matched 1 ops after 2 passes. cpus(*) 11.5; mem(*) 23106.0; disk(*) 4942.0; ports(*) 31000->31622,31624->32000 left. (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:57,293] INFO receiveTaskUpdate: updating status of task [basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889] (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19)
[2016-07-29 13:27:57,312] INFO Task launch for 'task [basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889]' was accepted. 0 tasksToLaunch, 0 in flight, 1 confirmed.  not backing off (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:58,667] INFO Received status update for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889: TASK_FAILED (Failed to launch container: Container exited on error: exited with status 1) (mesosphere.marathon.MarathonScheduler$$EnhancerByGuice$$9250fa1f:Thread-37)
[2016-07-29 13:27:58,723] INFO Removed app [/basic-3] from tracker (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.tracker.TaskTracker$TasksByApp$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3)
[2016-07-29 13:27:58,735] INFO receiveTaskUpdate: task [basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889] finished (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3)
[2016-07-29 13:27:58,739] INFO Sending event notification for task [basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889] of app [/basic-3]: TASK_FAILED (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.steps.PostToEventStreamStepImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$42a76347:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3)
[2016-07-29 13:27:58,740] INFO Increasing delay. Task launch delay for [/basic-3] changed from [0 milliseconds] to [1 seconds]. (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.RateLimiter$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:58,743] INFO initiating a scale check for app [/basic-3] after task [basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889] terminated (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.steps.ScaleAppUpdateStepImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$78bdbf3a:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:58,743] INFO schedulerActor: Actor[akka://marathon/user/MarathonScheduler#1328539013] (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.steps.ScaleAppUpdateStepImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$78bdbf3a:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-07-29 13:27:58,747] WARN New task [task [basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889]] failed during app /basic-3 scaling, queueing another task (mesosphere.marathon.upgrade.TaskStartActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
```

**Mesos Master Logs**

```
I0729 13:27:56.987308 20184 master.cpp:3720] Processing REVIVE call for framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-88ef4a70-96ae-4294-a286-ba0a955b193a@xx.xx.xx.xxx:54704
I0729 13:27:56.987633 20184 hierarchical.cpp:988] Removed offer filters for framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:56.989745 20176 master.cpp:5324] Sending 1 offers to framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-88ef4a70-96ae-4294-a286-ba0a955b193a@xx.xx.xx.xxx:54704
I0729 13:27:57.314573 20183 master.cpp:3104] Processing ACCEPT call for offers: [ b2501f80-c821-4b1a-9f67-c008739a4e06-O1 ] on slave 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7 at slave(1)@xx.xx.xx.xxx:5051 (xx.xx.xx.xxx) for framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-88ef4a70-96ae-4294-a286-ba0a955b193a@xx.xx.xx.xxx:54704
I0729 13:27:57.321236 20180 master.hpp:177] Adding task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 with resources cpus(*):0.5; mem(*):32; disk(*):32; ports(*):[31623-31623] on slave 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7 (xx.xx.xx.xxx)
I0729 13:27:57.321815 20180 master.cpp:3589] Launching task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-88ef4a70-96ae-4294-a286-ba0a955b193a@xx.xx.xx.xxx:54704 with resources cpus(*):0.5; mem(*):32; disk(*):32; ports(*):[31623-31623] on slave 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7 at slave(1)@xx.xx.xx.xxx:5051 (xx.xx.xx.xxx)
I0729 13:27:57.554368 20177 master.cpp:5324] Sending 1 offers to framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-88ef4a70-96ae-4294-a286-ba0a955b193a@xx.xx.xx.xxx:54704
I0729 13:27:57.561040 20181 master.cpp:3641] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ b2501f80-c821-4b1a-9f67-c008739a4e06-O2 ] for framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-88ef4a70-96ae-4294-a286-ba0a955b193a@xx.xx.xx.xxx:54704
W0729 13:27:58.653374 20181 master.cpp:4859] Ignoring unknown exited executor 'basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889' of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 on slave 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7 at slave(1)@xx.xx.xx.xxx:5051 (xx.xx.xx.xxx)
I0729 13:27:58.660586 20181 master.cpp:4763] Status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 7cb5dc80-8c90-4933-83a1-c68e4a1369bf) for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 from slave 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7 at slave(1)@xx.xx.xx.xxx:5051 (xx.xx.xx.xxx)
I0729 13:27:58.660701 20181 master.cpp:4811] Forwarding status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 7cb5dc80-8c90-4933-83a1-c68e4a1369bf) for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000
I0729 13:27:58.661497 20181 master.cpp:6421] Updating the state of task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 (latest state: TASK_FAILED, status update state: TASK_FAILED)
I0729 13:27:58.749291 20181 master.cpp:3918] Processing ACKNOWLEDGE call 7cb5dc80-8c90-4933-83a1-c68e4a1369bf for task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-88ef4a70-96ae-4294-a286-ba0a955b193a@xx.xx.xx.xxx:54704 on slave 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7
I0729 13:27:58.749658 20181 master.cpp:6487] Removing task basic-3.29606d60-5562-11e6-82c4-02010a552889 with resources cpus(*):0.5; mem(*):32; disk(*):32; ports(*):[31623-31623] of framework 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-0000 on slave 09894fa6-e1fa-4d26-aaca-0ea6c8fb06da-S7 at slave(1)
```

**Mesos Slave Kernel logs:**

```
Jul 29 13:28:07 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.110000] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethe4b2f1c: link is not ready
Jul 29 13:28:07 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.110012] docker0: port 1(vethe4b2f1c) entered forwarding state
Jul 29 13:28:07 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.110028] docker0: port 1(vethe4b2f1c) entered forwarding state
Jul 29 13:28:07 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.111114] docker0: port 1(vethe4b2f1c) entered disabled state
Jul 29 13:28:07 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.505747] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethe4b2f1c: link becomes ready
Jul 29 13:28:07 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.505810] docker0: port 1(vethe4b2f1c) entered forwarding state
Jul 29 13:28:07 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.505824] docker0: port 1(vethe4b2f1c) entered forwarding state
Jul 29 13:28:08 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.979072] docker0: port 1(vethe4b2f1c) entered disabled state
Jul 29 13:28:08 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.980744] device vethe4b2f1c left promiscuous mode
Jul 29 13:28:08 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175212.980783] docker0: port 1(vethe4b2f1c) entered disabled state
Jul 29 13:28:12 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175217.043575] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[8836]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Jul 29 13:28:12 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175217.081090] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[8836]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Jul 29 13:28:12 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175217.128271] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[8836]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Jul 29 13:28:12 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175217.149756] device vethb70e796 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 29 13:28:12 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175217.150008] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethb70e796: link is not ready
Jul 29 13:28:12 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175217.576723] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethb70e796: link becomes ready
Jul 29 13:28:12 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175217.576805] docker0: port 1(vethb70e796) entered forwarding state
Jul 29 13:28:12 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175217.576819] docker0: port 1(vethb70e796) entered forwarding state
Jul 29 13:28:13 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175218.107877] docker0: port 1(vethb70e796) entered disabled state
Jul 29 13:28:13 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175218.109620] device vethb70e796 left promiscuous mode
Jul 29 13:28:13 test-lab-test-infra-reserved-4001279 kernel: [175218.109662] docker0: port 1(vethb70e796) entered disabled state
```

Comment: While debugging container config I found **"echo 'No such file or directory'; exit 1"** as command. That is why container is stopping. Can any one help me in debugging why Marathon/Mesos is sending **"echo 'No such file or directory'; exit 1"** in command and argument?

`"Args":["-c","echo 'No such file or directory'; exit 1"]
"Cmd":["-c","echo 'No such file or directory'; exit 1"]`

Comment: You should add the Marathon app definition JSON. Also, is 32MB really enough to run the container?

Comment: What Tobi said. I'd suggest you use the `docker stats` command when you run the container from the command line and figure out how much memory it really consumes. If it's more than 32MB and you launch it in Marathon the mem cgroup will kick in and kill it. Of course you could also simply try setting `mem` to somthing way higher, like 500 and see if it still gets killed.

Comment: Here is Marathon app JSON. `{"id":"/basic-3","cmd":"/bin/bash","cpus":0.5,"mem":32,"disk":32,"instances":1,"container":{"type":"DOCKER","volumes":[],"docker":{"image":"python:3","network":"BRIDGE","portMappings":[{"containerPort":8080,"hostPort":0,"servicePort":10000,"protocol":"tcp","labels":{}}],"privileged":false,"parameters":[],"forcePullImage":false}},"portDefinitions":[{"port":10000,"protocol":"tcp","labels":{}}]}`

Comment: @Tobi, its not related to memory which I am assigning, even I am not able to run any container. Increasing mem or disk is not making any change. I tried it and got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, finally got the solution here:

https://github.com/mesos/elasticsearch/issues/276

Sumit

Comment: So, what's the actual solution? That's not really an answer I'm afraid...

Comment: @Tobi While starting Mesos Slave binary I was not setting launcher_dir & LD_LIBRARY_PATH flags values. Due to this it was throwing error. After setting these flags everything works fine.